# react-oidc-context redirects to originating route after successful login with auth0

Tags: reactjs, react-router, openid-connect, react-oidc

Hi I'm trying to use react-oidc-context to authenticate with auth0 and I have one problem. After successful authentication with auth0 I always get redirected back to the route I was on when I clicked the login button. The app has 2 unprotected routes /login and /public and I could be on either of those when I click login in the page header. I always get redirected to whichever of these pages I was on initially. The login button calls login from the useReactOidc hook. I want to be redirected to the /home route and have tried doing a history.push('/home') before calling login() but no luck.

In the case of the login page I could include logic to redirect to /home if we're logged in as we don't need to be there, but in the case of /public you could have a reason to be on the page if logged in or not.

I'm not really getting how the redirect_uri in the configuration fits into this, I've tried setting up a route for this but it never matches (<SecuredRoute path='/authentication/callback' ...). If anyone has any suggestions for how to redirect to a specific route upon successful login it would be greatfully appreciated, hopefully I've just missed something obvious. Thanks and here's the code:

configuration.js

```
const tenancy = 'https://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu.auth0.com';
const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

export const configuration = {
  client_name: 'My App',
  client_id: clientId,
  scope: 'openid profile',
  response_type: 'code',
  authority: `${tenancy}`,
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/authentication/callback',
  // post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000', // Auth0 uses returnTo
  silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/authentication/silent_callback',
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
  metadata: {
    issuer: `${tenancy}/`,
    authorization_endpoint: `${tenancy}/authorize`,
    token_endpoint: `${tenancy}/oauth/token`,
    userinfo_endpoint: `${tenancy}/userinfo`,
    end_session_endpoint: `${tenancy}/v2/logout?returnTo=${encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000')}&client_id=${clientId}`
  }
};
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { AuthenticationProvider, oidcLog, InMemoryWebStorage } from '@axa-fr/react-oidc-context';
import { configuration } from './configuration';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthenticationProvider
      configuration={configuration}
      loggerLevel={oidcLog.DEBUG}
      isEnabled={true}
      callbackComponentOverride={() => (<></>)}
      UserStore={InMemoryWebStorage}>
      <App />
    </AuthenticationProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useReactOidc } from '@axa-fr/react-oidc-context';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SecuredRoute from './SecuredRoute';
import { PageHeader, Space } from 'antd';

import './App.css';

const Login = () => <h3>Login Page - use the Login button top right</h3>;
const Home = () => <h3>Home Page</h3>;
const Public = () => <h3>Public Page</h3>;

const Header = () => {
  const { oidcUser, login, logout } = useReactOidc();

  return (
    <PageHeader style={{ textAlign: "right", margin: "8px" }}>
      { oidcUser ? (
        <button onClick={logout}>Log Out</button>
      ) : (
          <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
        )}
    </PageHeader>
  );
};

const DefaultPage = () => {
  const { oidcUser } = useReactOidc();

  return (
    oidcUser ? (
      <Redirect to="/home" />
      ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    )
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={DefaultPage} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route path='/public' component={Public} />
          <SecuredRoute path='/home' component={Home} />
          <SecuredRoute path='/authentication/callback' component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        <Space>
          <Link to="/home">Home Page (you must be logged in to access this)</Link>
          <br/>
          <Link to="/public">Public Page (you don't need to be logged in to access this)</Link>
        </Space>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

SecuredRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useReactOidc } from '@axa-fr/react-oidc-context';

const SecuredRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { oidcUser } = useReactOidc();
  
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      oidcUser
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }}} />
    )} />
  );
};
```

export default SecuredRoute;

Versions

```
"dependencies": {
"@axa-fr/react-oidc-context": "^3.1.6",
"@axa-fr/react-oidc-context-fetch": "^3.1.6",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
"antd": "^4.8.0",
"oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.0",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really help you with react-oidc-context, so this may only be a partial answer. It feels to me like you need some control over the following areas:

**REQUIREMENT 1: CONTROL BEFORE REDIRECTING**

The ability to do things like store the user's state and location in HTML5 storage before a redirect.

**REQUIREMENT 2: CONTROL AFTER HANDLING A LOGIN RESPONSE**

The ability to restore state from storage if needed, then control the post login location.

**REQUIREMENT 3: CONTROL OVER EXPIRY**

If a user leaves their browser running overnight, and tokens have expired, the UI may need to trigger a login redirect as the result of a failed API call.

**OIDC CLIENT**

This library fully supports the above behaviour. If you cannot get the same control with react-oidc-context, then one solution that will work is to use the library directly - it may be one less layer to manage.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

I would aim to have a couple of functions as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L125) that give you the control you need before and after logins.

**REACT CODE**

My personal preference is to use React only for views, and plain classes for API calls and Open Id Connect. Here also is a sample of mine [here](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) that follows this approach, though this sample is a little complicated.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for the link to your code. react-oidc-context uses oidc-client under the hood so it looks like direct use of the underlying package will provide the required level of control, thanks for your help.